# Ages of humans of each yuga

Tags: yuga

Human age in Satya yuga was 100,000 years; 10,000 in Treta; 1000 in Dwapar and 100 in Kali yuga. Is it just symbolic and means something? Also were humans of Satya yuga and Treta yuga physically different from us? Do Upanishads talk about yuga cycle?

Comment: No, Upanishads don't talk about the Yuga cycle. Souls are birthless and deathless, that's what most Upanishads say. Vedas assert 100 years lifespan of human beings. Out of which 1/4th - 25 years is designated for marriage, and 3/4th of 75 years for sanyas. But I don't exactly remember where this was.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha - you are spouting a lot of wrong information. 25 years is for bramhachari (student), next 25 for gruhastha (marriage), next 25 for vanaprasth (retirement), last 25 for sanyas (renouncing).

Comment: @mar I mentioned I don't remember that exact source of reading the age chart. Thanks for the correction.